# Argument of type '() => JQuery<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, typescript

I have ts code to use with jquery autocomplete

Here is code

```
    function load_autocomplete_fields(){
    $('.airport_field').each(function() {
      $(this).autocomplete({
        delay:10,
        minLength: 0,
        source(request, response) {
          $(this.element[0]).attr('data-req-term', request.term);
          $.ajax({
            url: $(this.element[0]).attr('data-source'),
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
              term: request.term
            },
            success(data) {
              const results = [];
              $.map(data.cities, function(value, key) {
                results.push(value);
                return $.map(value.airports, (value2, key2) => results.push(value2));
              });
              $.map(data.airports, (value, key) => results.push(value));
              return response(results);},
            error() { return response([]); }
          });
          return null;},
        focus(event, ui) {
          return false;},
        select(event, ui) {
          const qel = $(event.currentTarget);
          qel.val(ui.item.fullname);
          $(qel.attr('data-id-element')).val(ui.item.id);
          return false;}
      }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return create_autocomplete_item($(this.element[0]), ul, item);
    };
    $('.airport_field').on('autocompleteselect', function() {
      if (this.id.indexOf('origin') !== -1) {
        const id = this.id.split('_')[2];
        return $(`#search_legs_${id}_destination_text`).focus();
      }
    });
    return $('.airport_field').focus(function() {
      if (!$(this).val()) { return $(this).val(' ').keydown(); }
    });
  });
  }
```

When I try to compile it I have this error

> Argument of type '() => JQuery' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: HTMLElement, index: number, element: HTMLElement) => false | void'.
>     Type 'JQuery' is not assignable to type 'false | void'.
>       Type 'JQuery' is not assignable to type 'void'.

in this row `$('.airport_field').each(function() {`

Here is HTML

```
<ul>
<li>
  <div class="header"><%= _('Från') %></div>
  <%= text_field_tag 'search[legs][0][origin_text]', @default_lsp[:legs][0][:origin_city][:return],
                     class: 'field-1 airport_field', placeholder: _('Från'),
                     "data-source" => '/autocomplete/origin/flight',
                     "data-id-element" => '#search_legs_0_origin_id' %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'search[legs][0][origin_id]', @default_lsp[:legs][0][:origin_id] %>
  <div class="quick-destinations hide-small"><%= generate_quick_links_html.html_safe %></div>
</li>
<li class="icon"><%= image_tag 'shared/right_left_arrow.png', class: 'right_left_arrow', "data-number" => 0 %></li>
<li>
  <div class="header"><%= _('Till') %></div>
  <%= text_field_tag 'search[legs][0][destination_text]', @default_lsp[:legs][0][:destination_city][:return],
                     class: 'field-3 airport_field', placeholder: _('Till'),
                     "data-source" => '/autocomplete/destination/flight',
                     "data-id-element" => '#search_legs_0_destination_id' %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'search[legs][0][destination_id]', @default_lsp[:legs][0][:destination_id] %>
</li>
```

How I can solve it?

Comment: Please show your HTML.

Comment: Updated comment@SmitRaval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
return $('.airport_field').focus(function () {
      if (!$(this).val()) { return $(this).val(' ').keydown(); }
    });
```

Why are you *returning* the result of that call?  The `each()` method doesn't want you to return anything unless you want to stop the iteration early, in which case you should return `false`. That's what the error is telling you:

> `Argument of type '() => JQuery' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: HTMLElement, index: number, element: HTMLElement) => false | void'. Type 'JQuery' is not assignable to type 'false | void'. Type 'JQuery' is not assignable to type 'void'.`

means

> The function is returning a `JQuery`, which isn't appropriate.  It should return `false` or `void`, and `JQuery` isn't either one of those.  Specifically, it's not `void`.

Maybe you should change the above line to just

```
$('.airport_field').focus(function () {
    if (!$(this).val()) { return $(this).val(' ').keydown(); }
  });
```

without the `return` and see if it works.

Hope that helps.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, funny isn't it. Sometimes it requires some-one else to read the error for us. I knew that returning `false` was to break out, so just assumed that returning `true` was ok